# How to calculate the difference between 2 consecutive dataframes using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am fairly new in using pandas I have the following dataframe:

```
Date
2019-06-01    195.585770
2019-07-01    210.527466
2019-08-01    206.278168
2019-09-01    222.169479
2019-10-01    246.760193
2019-11-01    265.101562
2019-12-01    292.163818
2020-01-01    307.943604
2020-02-01    271.976532
2020-03-01    253.603500
2020-04-01    293.006836
2020-05-01    317.081665
2020-06-01    331.500000
2020-06-05    331.500000
Name: AAPL, dtype: float64
```

How can I quickly calculate the difference between 2 dates in days? In the end I want to calculate the average monthly increase percentage-wise.
The result should be that the difference is alternately 30 and 31 days. There must be a quick command to calculate the difference between two consecutive dates but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: Can I make a note?  Your print out here indicates you have a pd.Series not a pd.DataFrame.

Comment: Look at the `pct_change` method.

Comment: Aha yes, I checked and it is indeed a pd.Series.

Comment: I did, I use it. However it seems that it gives me a difference in values but I want to divide this percentage by the days that have passed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do `pct_change` and `mean`:

```
df['AAPL'].pct_change().mean()
```

Or in case your series:

```
s.pct_change().mean()
```

---

If you want to find out the daily percentage change:

```
s.pct_change()/s.index.to_series().diff().dt.days
```

Output:

```
Date
2019-06-01         NaN
2019-07-01    0.002546
2019-08-01   -0.000651
2019-09-01    0.002485
2019-10-01    0.003689
2019-11-01    0.002398
2019-12-01    0.003403
2020-01-01    0.001742
2020-02-01   -0.003768
2020-03-01   -0.002329
2020-04-01    0.005012
2020-05-01    0.002739
2020-06-01    0.001467
2020-06-05    0.000000
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you already have your answer, but this may be useful in some other instances.

You can use the *df.itterows()* to easily grab the difference in dates. First, make sure you convert your *Date* row to datetime. Then iterate over the rows and grab the difference.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'Date':['2020-04-01','2020-05-01','2020-06-01','2020-06-05 '], 'Col2':['195.585770','210.527466','331.500000','331.500000']})
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']) #convert to datetime
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if not index == 0:
        print(row['Date'] - df['Date'][index-1])
```

The output will look like this:

```
30 days 00:00:00
31 days 00:00:00
4 days 00:00:00
```